# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' in uwsgi log

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, nginx, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi with django and nginx in my live server but it is giving me an error that 'upstream prematurely closed connection nginx uwsgi'. After googling I've found that it is not the issue of nginx, rather than uwsgi. Thus I check my uwsgi log and found

```
    return render(request, 'webclient/404.html')   File
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py",
line 49, in render
    context_instance = RequestContext(request, current_app=current_app)   File
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py",
line 179, in __init__
    self.update(processor(request))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
line 24, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user): AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' [pid: 10878|app: 0|req: 6/7] 125.64.35.67 ()
{38 vars in 717 bytes} [Fri Nov 14 10:13:10 2014] GET
/zc/chs/img/body.png =>generated 0 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0
headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0) [pid: 10878|app: 0|req: 7/8]
127.0.0.1 () {30 vars in 414 bytes} [Fri Nov 14 22:56:41 2014] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 3 headers in 126 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: did you write test_func? when does this happen? the `request` object is missing the user attribute

Comment: No I didn't write that test_func. While I was trying to test from browser that my configuration of nginx and uwsgi were correct or not.

Comment: Now I manage it by using two application server like apache and nginx just by passing wsgi requests to apache. Nginx is used for serving static files and apache is used for wsgi requests.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py solves this

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'BruteBuster.middleware.RequestMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',

)
```